# Resolving php56w-common conflicts with php-common for PHP OAuth Package

Tags: php, oauth, pecl, php-5.6

I am need to enable PHP OAuth for a QuickBooks integration.  I am working on a centos 6 system.  My attempts to install php-pecl-oauth via yum throws this error:

```
 php56w-common-5.6.27-1.w6.i386 conflicts php-common
```

I tried adding --skip-broken, but that doesn't resaolve the issue; it just skips the package I am trying to install.  I also tried yum install php56-pecl-oauth, but that package doesn't exist.

I've tried googling and haven't found a real hit yet. Anyone know how to overcome this?